# How to optimize performance of my WAMP with 15000 users

Tags: php, mysql, apache2, wamp

I have a web development now with 15,000 users. And they access the site at the same time and the site cant cater them anymore. Anyone can help me with this?

Comment: Maybe this [http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/18614/wamp-server-performance-tuning-for-mysql](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/18614/wamp-server-performance-tuning-for-mysql) can help you

Comment: The question is too vague. You need to find out where you performance bottleneck is (Server? Client? Apache? PHP? MySQL?) and then we can perhaps advise.

Comment: thank you for your reply. the bottleneck is in the server side (apache) can't  when 9000 users access at the same time the website can't be display. Is there any setting for the apache for huge number of users accessing at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

You should improve the performance of your server. You should also optimize your website, page caching, database query caching. Have you checked the speed of your website? You can check it on webpagetest.

Comment: i have tested my site to webpagetest and here's the result.[link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2NqcaAYvjR-T0kxNV8tUWl1X1E/view?usp=sharing). Is there any setting of apache for 15000 users accessing at the same time.

Comment: May be its because of the bandwidth. Please check your website bandwidth. You can calculate the bandwidth for your website from https://www.easycalculation.com/other/website-traffic-bandwidth.php